# Difference: &ary1D[0] and &ary1D

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have in my main-Function an double Array:

```
double ary1D[4] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
```

and have a function call:

```
print1D_A(&ary1D[0],Num);
```

my function:

```
void print1D_A(double *ary1D, int Num);
```

so my question is, Whats is the difference between **&ary1D[0]** and **&ary1D**. My compiler give me an error, if I call the function with **&ary1D**. But the argument **&ary1D** is the first Adress of my Array, just like **&ary1D[0]**.

Can I change the argumentlist of my function, that I can call it with

```
print1D_A(&ary1D,Num);
```

Comment: Care to share that error? As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your code, it's also customary to extract a [mcve]. BTW: C++ is more strict than C, which often lets you off with a warning. Make sure you read and understand said warning!

Comment: All of these are the same address, `ary1D`, `&ary1D[0]` and `&ary1D`. The difference is the **type** of the pointer. The first two are a pointer to the first element (i.e. `double*`), the last is a pointer to the array itself, i.e. `double (*)[4]`

Comment: Note that many of us "oldies" dislike the term "C/C++". There is no language "C/C++", only the two (very) different languages C and C++. And while some things might seem similar in both languages, there might be minute differences in the specifications that means the behavior could be vastly different.

Comment: Answer to your second question is yes, change your function signature to `void print1D_A(double (*ary1D)[4], int Num);` but really it's not a good idea.

Comment: *Why* do you want to change the signature of the function? *Why* do you want to pass a pointer to the array? What problem is that supposed to solve? What is you *real* and *actual* problem that lead you to write this question?

Comment: Wow, thanks! I have no problem. I want to understand, how arrays/pointers are work.. Thank you all..

Comment: @Fkcm95 It's good to want to learn these things but practically pointers to arrays are very obscure, and almost never used.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `&ary1D[0]` is a pointer to the first element of `ary1D`. Its type is `double*`. This is also what plain `ary1D` *decays* to, so you could just do

```
print1D_A(ary1D,Num);
```

The expression `&ary1D` is a pointer to the *array*. Its type is `double (*)[4]`.

Now, both pointers are pointing to the same location, but as you can see their types are very different. That could lead to errors if a function is expecting one type and you give the other.

Comment: @Fkcm95 You need to make it accept the type `double(*)[4]`. But then you can't pass `&ary1D[0]` (or `ary1D`) as the type from that expression will no longer match.